# Is there a to export transaction level data from an aggregated Power BI dashboard?

Tags: powerbi

We are building a reporting solution using Power BI. We have OLPT data source. It is aggregated and loaded into a data mart. Power BI dashboards will source data from data mart in aggregated format.

Now the requirement is that, there should be download icon on the Power BI dashboard. On clicking the download icon the transactional data should be exported to CSV instead of aggregated data.

Example:

OLTP Data:
Order_No    Qty    Status
1           10     Delivered
2           8      Pending
3           5      Failed
4           3      Delivered

Aggregated data (in Datamart):
Status           Order_Count
Delivered        2
Failed           1
Pending          1

[image: PBI Tile]

When the download icon clicked, the following data should be exported to CSV and downloaded in users local system.

Order_No    Qty    Status
1           10     Delivered
2           8      Pending
3           5      Failed
4           3      Delivered

Comment: No you can't do this in Power BI. You'll have to expose the transactional data another way. You could do this with a SSRS/Power BI Paginated Reports and a sub-query and report, but you'll be running an query on a OLTP database, which may have performance/capacity impacts

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for your input. However we may need to download 1 to 50 million records. Please let me know if there is any limitation on the number of rows which can be downloaded using pagination approach.

Comment: @Jon can we make a call to service through Power BI to download Transactional reports?

Comment: No you can't make a call. If you're downloading 1 to 50m records, don't use the reporting front end tools